# How to use ajax to post json string to controller method?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to be able to `post` a json string to a control action but it's always receive the string as `null`. If I create a view model for the controller method, it works, but that's not what I want since there will be too much view models to maintain.

controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Test(string json){
    // debugger stops here, but json is null. why?
    dynamic item = Json.Parse(json);
    var temp = item.prop1;
    return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
}
```

javascript

```
var data = {
    prop1: 'test',
    prop2: 'test2',
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'approot\Test',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(json) {
        if (json) {
            alert('ok');
        } else {
            alert('failed');
        }
    },
});
```

**Thanks Stephen Muecke's hint, I got it working this way:**

controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Test(string json){
    dynamic item = JObject.Parse(json);
    var temp = item.prop1;
    return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
}
```

javascript

```
var json = {
    prop1: 'test',
    prop2: 'test2',
};

var data = {
    json: JSON.stringify(json),
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'approot\Test',
    data: data,
    // contentType: 'application/json', <-- no need this.
    success: function(json) {
        if (json) {
            alert('ok');
        } else {
            alert('failed');
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: Remove `contentType: 'application/json'` and use `data: data,` (no `JSON.stringify()` then change the method to `public JsonResult Test(string prop1) {` (`prop1` will contain the value `'test'`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I removed `contentType` and use `data`, but still get `null`. However, I can't just use `Test(string prop1)` since the json could contain multiple attributes and the attributes can be unknown at runtime.

Comment: Are you even hitting the controller - `url: 'approot\Test',` should be `url: '/approot/Test',` (or to do it correctly, then `url: '@Ul.Action("Test", "approot")',`

Comment: Can I ask what the method is returning in the success function(json){ if (json){alert("ok")}?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your action method is expecting a string. Create a javascript object, give it the property "data" and stringify your data object to send along.

Updated code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'approot\Test',
    data: { "json": JSON.stringify(data) },
    success: function (json) {
        if (json) {
            alert('ok');
        } else {
            alert('failed');
        }
    },
});
```