# How can I post the data that coming from Ajax?

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My script code is below. Here, how do I save my exits_response data that I received as a response to the database in the controller? In post action result the parameter "variable " is coming null. When there is no post code in ajax,response returns and shows me the "exist_response". I have not written the process of registering to the controller because I am getting null data while posting.

**I solved the problem, I defined the data variable incorrectly.**

**js code**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js%22%3E</script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#submit').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var exist_response = $.ajax({ type: "GET", url: "https://heroku-diagnosis.herokuapp.com/predict", data: "Symptom_1=" + $('#Symptom_1').val() + "&Symptom_2=" + $('#Symptom_2').val() +
            "&Symptom_3=" + $('#Symptom_3').val() + "&Symptom_4=" + $('#Symptom_4').val() + "&Symptom_5=" + $('#Symptom_5').val() + "&Symptom_6=" +
            $('#Symptom_6').val() + "&Symptom_7=" + $('#Symptom_7').val() + "&Symptom_8=" + $('#Symptom_8').val() + "&Symptom_9=" + $('#Symptom_9').val() + "&Symptom_10=" + $('#Symptom_10').val() +
            "&Symptom_11=" + $('#Symptom_11').val(),async: false}).responseText;
             $('#output').text("According to the symptoms you have entered, you may have a " +exist_response + " disease. Make an appointment on our website to consult a doctor. " );

           $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"/Prediction/Index",
        data: { variable: exist_response },
        success: function(response){
           alert(response);
        }});



        </script>
```

**controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(String variable,int id)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: This post needs  more details.

Comment: I am sorry but I can't see any expalanations what the first ajax has to do  with the second one?. What is output?  And which ajax is not working properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a string already. But you stringified it again using JSON.stringify(exist_response). So you sent double stringifyed object.
Try this

```
$.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"/Prediction/Index",
            data: { variable: exist_response },
            success: function(response){
               alert(response);
            }
});
```

Update:

If you want to send Id to the controller you can do it this way

```
var id= ...your code;

$.ajax({
          ....
            data: {  variable: exist_response, id: id },
          ...
});
```

Comment: thank you very much Sergey. It worked now but what was wrong in code can you share reason with me? @Sergey

Comment: You are welcome. I added some comments to my answer.

Comment: I need to send the id of my model with exist_response in the Controller section. I rearranged the controller part of the issue. How can I send the model id?

Comment: I did ,you are the best!  @Sergey

Answer (score 0):

To correctly pass data to controller method via ajax post request you must specify "variable" argument name:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"/Prediction/Index",
    data: { variable: JSON.stringify(exist_response) },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
       alert(response);
    }
});
```

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991153/how-to-use-ajax-to-post-json-string-to-controller-method)

Comment: @BorishSh When we do it like this, our first ajax with get does not work and it comes to null again.

Comment: @learningwoman  just remove dataType: "json"  and stringify and this ajax will be working properly